# Does Fluent NHibernate support "trigger-identity"

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I posted the question in the Fluent-NHibernate newgroup but so far there has been no answer from the void.

Is there a Fluent NHibernate mapping for the NHibernate "trigger-identity" method of generating primary keys.

Thanks

Comment: If you use GenerateBy.Identity() does it fails ?

Comment: GenerateBy.Identity() uses a hibernate sequence and generates the following SQL
INSERT INTO schema.table (table_id,...) VALUES (schema.hibernate.sequence, ...) returning table_id into :nhIdOutParam

The entities in question have their IDs assigned by a trigger that generates the ID before insertion.

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep this discussion up-to-date :

```
this.Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
```

-> Fluent NHibernate V.1.1.0.685

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
this.Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Custom("trigger-identity");
```

Comment: tried this with Fluent build 636 and it works (need this for my project, too)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that trigger-identity is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only solution I've found is to use an hbm.xml file for those entities that require trigger-identity generators.  However, we ran into another problem when using trigger-identity and "long" ids and our Oracle database .  There is a bug where NHibernate does not translate the Id values returned from properly.  Here is the JIRA entry:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1893

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with FluentNHibernate v2.0.50727

Following mapping works fine:
this.Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();

Following mapping is not supported anymore:
this.Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Custom("trigger-identity");